# Writing/Designing a simple object manager (game context)

Tags: c++, c++11

There are multiple parts to this question, which is why the title is a bit vague. Some of the syntax is left off for sake of brevity. Most of this is just using some convenient examples for learning, what I mean by that may become apparent.

I started off with something like this:

```
class EntityManager {
    // ...
  private:
    map<string, Entity> _entities;
}
// definition of some add method
void EntityManager::add ( ... ) {
    _entities.emplace( std::piecewise_construct,
                       std::forward_as_tuple( ... ),
                       /* and so on */ );
}
```

where the map would hold the entire game entity (which is fixed in size), and adding would involve `emplace`.

**Question 1.** Is this smart? Or is it inefficient in some way vs holding onto a pointer as the value in the map?

**Question 2.** Say that `Entity` (or some sub-class) became dynamic in size in some way. Is there anything to stop this approach from handling it?

I'm assuming that `emplace` will allocate the object on the heap and maintain an internal pointer. I can write a `get` method like this to treat it like a reference.

```
Entity& EntityManager::get(std::string entityId)
{
    auto results = _gameEntities.find(entityId);
    if (results == _gameEntities.end()) {
        return Entity(); //this is bad, right?
    }

    return results->second;
}
```

**Question 3.** Of course, returning a reference to a local stack-allocated object is bad. Since I can't return NULL, is the only solution here to use exceptions?

The only other "problem" with this `map<string, Entity>` approach I've noticed, is that I can only make modifications to a game object that I'm creating by first `add`ing it, then requesting a reference to it with `get`, and then making my modifications. That's a little ugly, and also adds some overhead to object creation.

So now, I switch to a pointer design:

```
class EntityManager {
    // ...
  private:
    map<string, unique_ptr<Entity>> _entities;
}
```

That gives me two options for how to handle adding items

```
// OPTION 1: create a unique_ptr elsewhere, then move it.

void EntityManager::add( string id, unique_ptr<Entity> ptr) {
    _entities.insert( std::make_pair(id, std::move(ptr)) );
}

// object creation
unique_ptr<Entity> uPtr(new Entity());
_entityManager.add("entity1", std::move(uPtr));

// OR

// OPTION 2: Create a naked pointer elsewhere, create a unique_ptr on insert

void EntityManager::add( string id, Entity* ptr ) {
    _entities.insert(make_pair(id, unique_ptr<Entity>(ptr)));
}

// object creation
Entity* e = new Entity();
_entityManager.add("entity1", e);
```

**Question 4.** Is there effectively any difference between these approaches? Or a preferred way?

I think that's all the specific items I have, thanks for reading. Actually...

**Question 5.** Is there anything jumping out as wrong/notable that I've missed?

Comment: **5 questions** in one!! That's not really fitting the intended SO Q/A format. May be better to ask **one** main question like e.g. _'What can I do to improve my `EntityManager` class design/implementation'_ and enumerate your points of doubt in a list.

Comment: And then post it on codereview.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to [Stack Exchange Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Sorry, the format doesn't really fit well for SO!

Comment: Bah, all right, I accept my mistake. Maybe my intention didn't come across. Would it be best to revise this? Delete and create another in the format you mentioned above?

Comment: _'Delete and create another in the format you mentioned above?'_ No not necessary. As you accepted as it is, I'll retract my down/close points. Just the minor edit I've been proposing would be nice perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for the input though. I'll make sure to follow that advice in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:** I don't see anything obviously wrong with that approach.  It seems reasonable to me from an efficiency standpoint.

**Question 2:** In C++, specific classes and types are always fixed-sized, so I don't understand your question.  When you talk about a type being dynamic-size, I can think of two interpretations:

- The class internally allocates and manages free-store memory, increasing the "actual" size of the object dynamically.  (This case also applies to a class that has such a "dynamic" data member, e.g. `std::string`.)  In this case, the type is structurally fixed-size, although semantically variable-size, but this is all hidden behind the type's constructors, destructor, and assignment operators.  Consequently, I would say it doesn't have a material impact on your design.
- The container is actually intended to hold heterogeneous types, related by a common base type.  In this case, you can't store the objects directly in the `map` (or other standard container), since they are designed to only hold homogeneous types.  You have to store a pointer or pointer-ish type (such as `shared_ptr<Entity>` or `unique_ptr<Entity>`), and you'll probably also need to make special considerations as to how these objects are created.  There are a lot of details and trade-offs in handling these questions, so I don't think I can give a concrete answer to this question without more specifics.

`emplace()` will allocate the object on the heap, but (most likely) only indirectly.  More specifically, your objects will be wrapped in internal node structures which are themselves allocated on the heap.  These node structures will contain your objects along with pointers to other nodes and/or other bookkeeping information maintained by the `map`.

**Question 3:**  If the object you're looking for may not exist, that is one reason to consider using pointers, since they are nullable and can be tested for `nullptr`.  If you must return a reference rather than a pointer, exceptions are a reasonable choice (as is implicitly adding the object, as you mention), but another option is to use a `static` prototype object and return a reference to that:

```
Entity &EntityManager::get( string const &entityId) {
    static Entity empty{};
    auto found = gameEntities_.find(entityId);
    if (found == end(gameEntities_) )
        return empty;
    return found->second;
}
// (Note that leading underscores are reserved identifiers
// in some contexts and some such identifiers are reserved
// everywhere, so I prefer to avoid them altogether.)
```

However, realize that this approach makes your object non-threadsafe since the same static entity may be used by multiple threads that are unaware of each other.  This issue goes away if `get()` returns an `Entity const &` rather than an `Entity &` since read-only variables are inherently threadsafe.  Another option is to make the `empty` variable thread-local, but that incurs some cost and also introduces some surprising behaviors if the `empty` value is changed --- changes will be visible through subsequent calls to `get()`.

**Question 4:** Yes, there is a material difference between these two approaches.  Specifically, *OPTION 2* is not exception-safe.  You are passing `id` by value to `add()` and then passing it by value into `make_pair()`.  These are two opportunities for `string`'s copy constructor to throw, which will leak `ptr`.

(Also, a minor point, in *OPTION 1*, you need to `move(uPtr)` at the call site since `unique_ptr<T>` is movable, but not copyable.)

**Question 5:** My comments are included in my answers to questions 1-4.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. Regarding your answer to Q4: what's the difference between the two options in terms of the string? They both seem to handle it the same. And what's the proper way? Use a reference or a pointer and then copy the value into the map? And regarding that "minor point", that was an oversight; but it still needs to be moved twice correct? Once into the method call, and once in the method body while inserting.

Comment: @esel, the difference between the two options is that in _OPTION 1_, the `new`-ed pointer is stored in a `unique_ptr` as soon as it is created, which means it won't leak even if copying `id` throws --- stack unwinding will destroy the `unique_ptr` and clean up the memory.  In _OPTION 2_, the pointer is left naked and susceptible to leakage until the construction of the pair in `make_pair()`.  By that point, you will have had one `string` construction and up to two `string` copies that may have thrown, leaking the raw pointer.

Comment: @esei, with regard to the "minor point", yes, you will have two moves.  Generally moves are cheap and no-throw, so that's not a major point of concern.  A move of a `unique_ptr` may even be as cheap as a simple pointer copy, or may in some cases be elided completely by the compiler.  But in any event, a move of a `unique_ptr` should never be more expensive than two pointer assignments.

Comment: Got it. The issue arises from "external" factors (in this case a potential issue from `string`), but there's no effective difference in the two pointer approaches if they were alone in the call.

Comment: @esel, these type of "external" factors are often the essence of exception safety, which is why it's recommended to always perform allocations inside constructors (or pass allocations directly to constructors) that have destructors that will clean them up.  That's why the second approach is preferable --- the caller can follow this best practice (while the first option precludes this), and the code becomes much more maintainable.

Comment: What's the preferred way to handle the string in a case like this? The copies aren't intensive here, but may be problematic for large strings? I suppose they too could be elided, but since you've noticed issues, I'm guessing there's a better practice.

Comment: @esel, the strings aren't really a problem here.  The underlying principle is RAII and exception safety, which is why the `new` should go immediately in a `unique_ptr`.  You can avoid one of the string copies by taking the string by reference, or you can avoid the other by `move()`ing into `make_pair`.  But you can't avoid both.